# How do i remove the root app(?)?

Tags: unrooting

I have a Samsung galaxy S7 that i rooted, but i want to unroot it because an app i need doesn't allow root.

I followed this tutorial when rooting my phone:

https://www.youtube.com/watchv=CEI75gZWUtc

So tried to unroot it first by unrooting in the superuser app, then factory resetting it, but the app still said that i was rooted. I couldn't find any trace of it being rooted and even tried looking with adb, but found nothing. Then i installed an app that blocks internet for selected apps (Net Blocker) and in the list of apps there are two apps that i think causes this. one named root with UID=0 under it and one named RootPA with no text under it.

My question is how can i remove these?

Comment: The best chance is to reinstall a full original firmware image, read [this](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-frija-samsung-firmware-downloader-checker.3910594/) how to download it. Note that rooting has triggers a "fuse" that can not be restored and thus some know related functions will not work even reinstalling an original FW version.

Comment: unrelated ([RootPA](https://gsec.hitb.org/materials/sg2019/D2%20-%20Launching%20Feedback-Driven%20Fuzzing%20on%20TrustZone%20TEE%20-%20Andrey%20Akimov.pdf) page 9). probably there is some check on bootloader lock